# Anagrams - how can I pass the below two test cases

Tags: java, string, char, anagram

Here is my code for whether two strings are anagrams or not

```
static boolean isAnagram(String a, String b) {
    if (a.length() != b.length()) return false;
    a = a.toLowerCase();
    b = b.toLowerCase();
    int m1=0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++){
        m1 += (int)a.charAt(i);
        m1 -= (int)b.charAt(i);

    }
        return m1==0;
}
```

My code fails for two test cases

- case 1: `String a="xyzw";`and `String b="xyxy";`
- case 2: `String a="bbcc";` and `String b="dabc";`

can anyone help me passing the above two cases?

Comment: I believe your code is correct. Since xyxy is not an anagram of xyzw.
Anagram means that using the same letters from a word, a different word can be created.
Example: `pot` and `top`.

Comment: code is not correct some special cases because you consider only sum of asci value in character in a string. but sometimes different characters can give same asci value.example jl=214 and nh=214 but these are not a anagram

Answer (score 7):

I think your code doesn't work because you sum up the code of characters but maybe answer is zero however their are not equal, for example: "ad" "bc"
the better way is to do this is to sort characters of strings, if they has same array length and same order, so two string are anagram.

```
static boolean isAnagram(String str1, String str2) {
    int[] str1Chars = str1.toLowerCase().chars().sorted().toArray();
    int[] str2Chars = str2.toLowerCase().chars().sorted().toArray();
    return Arrays.equals(str1Chars, str2Chars);
}
```

I hope this help you. (it is a little hard because I use stream to create and sort array of characters)

Comment: Yeah, I think I still do not "think" in streams, so missed this part.

Comment: If your problem solved, then please accept the answer, so that others will know the question is solved!!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import java.io.*; 

class GFG{ 

    /* function to check whether two strings are  
    anagram of each other */
    static boolean areAnagram(char[] str1, char[] str2) 
    { 
        // Get lenghts of both strings 
        int n1 = str1.length; 
        int n2 = str2.length; 

        // If length of both strings is not same, 
        // then they cannot be anagram 
        if (n1 != n2) 
            return false; 

        // Sort both strings 
        quickSort(str1, 0, n1 - 1); 
        quickSort(str2, 0, n2 - 1); 

        // Compare sorted strings 
        for (int i = 0; i < n1;  i++) 
            if (str1[i] != str2[i]) 
                return false; 

        return true; 
    } 

    // Following functions (exchange and partition  
    // are needed for quickSort) 
    static void exchange(char A[],int a, int b) 
    { 
        char temp; 
        temp = A[a]; 
        A[a]   = A[b]; 
        A[b]   = temp; 
    } 

    static int partition(char A[], int si, int ei) 
    { 
        char x = A[ei]; 
        int i = (si - 1); 
        int j; 

        for (j = si; j <= ei - 1; j++) 
        { 
            if(A[j] <= x) 
            { 
                i++; 
                exchange(A, i, j); 
            } 
        } 
        exchange (A, i+1 , ei); 
        return (i + 1); 
    } 

    /* Implementation of Quick Sort 
    A[] --> Array to be sorted 
    si  --> Starting index 
    ei  --> Ending index 
    */
    static void quickSort(char A[], int si, int ei) 
    { 
        int pi;    /* Partitioning index */
        if(si < ei) 
        { 
            pi = partition(A, si, ei); 
            quickSort(A, si, pi - 1); 
            quickSort(A, pi + 1, ei); 
        } 
    } 

    /* Driver program to test to print printDups*/
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        char str1[] = {'t','e','s','t'}; 
        char str2[] = {'t','t','e','w'}; 
        if (areAnagram(str1, str2)) 
            System.out.println("The two strings are"+ 
                             " anagram of each other"); 
        else
            System.out.println("The two strings are not"+ 
                               " anagram of each other"); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static boolean isAnagram(String a, String b) {
        if (a.length() != b.length())
            return false;
        a = a.toLowerCase();
        b = b.toLowerCase();
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> m1 = new HashMap<>(); // Key is ascii number, Value is count. For String a
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> m2 = new HashMap<>(); // Key is ascii number, Value is count. For String b
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            int an = (int) (a.charAt(i));
            int bn = (int) (b.charAt(i));
            // Add 1 to current ascii number. String a.
            if (m1.containsKey(an)) {
                m1.put(an, m1.get(an) + 1);
            }else {
                m1.put(an, 1);
            }
            // Add 1 to current ascii number. String b.
            if (m2.containsKey(bn)) {
                m2.put(bn, m2.get(bn) + 1);
            }else {
                m2.put(bn, 1);
            }
        }

        //Check both count equals().
        return m1.equals(m2);
    }
```

you should check per every letters.
If (ascii of a[0] == ascii of b[0] + 1) and (ascii of a[1] == ascii of b[1] - 1) It will return true because 1 - 1 is zero.
Sorry for very very complex code.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation isn't correct. While a pair of anagrams will always have the same length and the same sum of characters, this is not a sufficient condition. There are many pairs of strings that have the same length and the same sum of characters and are not anagrams. E.g., `"ad"` and `"bc"`.

A better implementation would count the number of times each character appears in each string and compare them. E.g.:

```
public static boolean isAnagram(String a, String b) {
    return charCounts(a).equals(charCounts(b));
}

private static Map<Integer, Long> charCounts(String s) {
    return s.chars()
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding character values is error prone logic, because `A+C` and `B+B` generate same number. The best option with this case is using Arrays. Look at the code below -

```
static boolean isAnagram(String a, String b) {
    if (a.length() != b.length()) return false;
    a = a.toLowerCase();
    b = b.toLowerCase();

    char[] charA = a.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(charA);

    char[] charB = b.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(charB);

    return Arrays.equals(charA, charB);
}
```

This should give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

**Check out below methods :**

```
/**
 * Java program - String Anagram Example.
 * This program checks if two Strings are anagrams or not
 */
public class AnagramCheck {

/*
 * One way to find if two Strings are anagram in Java. This method
 * assumes both arguments are not null and in lowercase.
 *
 * @return true, if both String are anagram
 */
public static boolean isAnagram(String word, String anagram){       
    if(word.length() != anagram.length()){
        return false;
    }

    char[] chars = word.toCharArray();

    for(char c : chars){
        int index = anagram.indexOf(c);
        if(index != -1){
            anagram = anagram.substring(0,index) + anagram.substring(index +1, anagram.length());
        }else{
            return false;
        }           
    }

    return anagram.isEmpty();
}

/*
 * Another way to check if two Strings are anagram or not in Java
 * This method assumes that both word and anagram are not null and lowercase
 * @return true, if both Strings are anagram.
 */
public static boolean iAnagram(String word, String anagram){
    char[] charFromWord = word.toCharArray();
    char[] charFromAnagram = anagram.toCharArray();       
    Arrays.sort(charFromWord);
    Arrays.sort(charFromAnagram);

    return Arrays.equals(charFromWord, charFromAnagram);
}


public static boolean checkAnagram(String first, String second){
    char[] characters = first.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder sbSecond = new StringBuilder(second);

    for(char ch : characters){
        int index = sbSecond.indexOf("" + ch);
        if(index != -1){
            sbSecond.deleteCharAt(index);
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    return sbSecond.length()==0 ? true : false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It will execute in the O(word.length).

```
public boolean checkForAnagram(String str1, String str2) {
    if (str1 == null || str2 == null || str1.length() != str2.length()) {
        return false;
    }
    return Arrays.equals(getCharFrequencyTable(str1), getCharFrequencyTable(str2));
}

private int[] getCharFrequencyTable(String str) {
    int[] frequencyTable = new int[256]; //I am using array instead of hashmap to make you realize that its a constant time operation.
    char[] charArrayOfStr = str.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    for(char c : charArrayOfStr) {
        frequencyTable[c] = frequencyTable[c]+1;
    }
    return frequencyTable;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the ascii values of characters in given strings and comparing them, which will not always give you correct results. Consider this:

`String a="acd"` and `String b="ccb"`

both of them will give you a sum of 296 but these are not anagrams.

You can count of occurrences of characters in both the string and compare them. In above example, it will give you {"a":1,"c":1,"d":1} and {"c":2,"b":1}.

Also,you can associate a prime number with each of the character set [a-z] where 'a' matches 2, 'b' matches 3, 'c' matches 5 and so on.

Next, you can calculate the multiplication of the prime numbers associated with characters in the given string. The multiplication follows associativity rules (x*y = y*x).

Example:

abc --> 2*3*5 = 30

cba --> 5*3*2 = 30

**Note:** If the string size is huge, this might not be the best approach as you might encounter overflow issues.